# Drawing a Composable view on another View's canvas

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a composable view:

```
@Composable
fun ComposableView(text : String)
{
    :
    :
}
```

I have another view `MyView`. I want that when `MyView` is inflated, it draws `ComposableView` in its `onDraw()` method at particular coordinates relative to `MyView`.

```
class MyView extends View
{
    :
    :
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c)
    {
        View view = getComposableView();  //returns ComposeView instance
        Point point = getCoordinates();
        view.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        view.layout(point.x, point.y, view.getMeasuredWidth(),view.getMeasuredHeight());

    }
}
```

But I am getting runtime crash with error while calling `view.measure`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot locate windowRecomposer; View androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView{71eac1b V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} is not attached to a window
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: The question you should be asking is whether you should be doing this in the first place. What are you trying to achieve?